# Trigger DevExtreme's context menu event in Selenium IDE via JS

Tags: javascript, testing, devexpress, selenium-ide, devextreme

I do some UI tests, in which user should does RMB click on `dxdatagrid` row to open custom context menu. And  I've encountered with a problem: Selenium IDE does not records RMB clicks. In that case I have wrote JS script which imitate right clicks on grid's row:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("element").item(0);
var ev = new MouseEvent("contextmenu", { bubbles: true });
el.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

When test is running, script succesfully performed but context menu did not open. Is there any possible solution to summon context menu?

I've aslo tried script which uses `document.createEvent("MouseEvents")` but it didn't help.